# Store Previous URL in AngularJs web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to store previous URL , this is not working please give me any idea to store previous url on click and i want to user on some other pages

```
$scope.plain_url = function() {
         console.log('--------------------------')
        $scope.temp_url = window.history.back();
       console.log('--------------------------')
       console.log($scope.temp_url)

     }
```

Comment: what type of routing do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a router then you can listen for specific event:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) { 
  // get information from "current"
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Or if you're just interested about previous browser URL (not the one changed by your angular app, by pushstate) you can use:

```
document.referrer
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: I want to show a url with id /acout/:id as link on different controller how can i achieve this ..

Comment: Currently i am using $cookies ::  $cookieStore.put('accoutUrl',account_url); for this but let me know if any better solution..